# Differentiate between ADB Device connected over USB and Wi-Fi

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have started flutter development. I am using VSCode for this. When I want to run my app, I have to select the device I want to test it on by clicking the option on the status bar at the left.

In there, I get 2 options, one for my phone with ADB over USB, and other for my phone(same as before) with ADB over Wifi.
I cannot determine which is which because both have the same name.

Is there a way for me to change the name of one of them?

[image: IMG]

Comment: But, why do you keep your phone connected to your system after using ADB over WIFI? And if you're using ADB over USB, then why do you connect ADB over WIFI? Why not just either one?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your Visual Studio code and reconnect your device. There shouldn't be duplicate names.

Comment: I have 2 connections for the same phone. And it is working correctly. It is just the names that is the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try using Android Studio, you will see two different names of the same devices.

Update:

the other solution is built the app by using the command line

```
flutter run
```

then you will see two options, one is SM G885F(xxx) which is connected by  USB,
the other one is SM G885F(192.168.x.xxx) which is connected with Wifi

You will also see this line if you upgrade the latest flutter version

```
Please choose one: [0|1]:
```

Just type 0 or 1 then enter you can build a debug version.

Build release by entering

```
flutter run --release
```

Comment: I tried but my PC is old and AStudio is lagging so much...
A reason why I am using my physical device for debugging rather than an AVM

Comment: @PhaniPavan the other solution is built the app by using the command line

flutter run 

then you will see two options, one is SM G885F(xxx) which is connected by  USB,
the other one is SM G885F(192.168.x.xxx) which is connected with Wifi

Comment: That is helpful, Thanks, but I want to just ```rename the device``` in VSCode...